# Access data from Google Nutrition Facts

Tags: google-search-api

is there a way to access the data Google shows up additionally when searching for a specific food? I would like to retrieve just the "Nutrition Facts" data.

Thanks in advance and cheers

Answer (score 1):

Google does not make nutrition information available via API.

If you are looking for an API for nutrition data, I recommend you check out: https://www.nutritionix.com/business/api

Full disclosure: I work for Nutritionix.